# How do I replace html elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have spent around 3 hours today trying to replace an html element on a page using JavaScript.

I have tried many things and haven't had much success.
For example, if I wanted to replace code snippet 1 with the code snippet 2, how would that be done?

I have tried

```
document.getElementById('wide-left').innerHTML="(code snippet 1)";
```

but it just throws an error.

Sorry if I didn't explain this clear enough, I tried my best.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code snippet 1**

```
<h4 id="select-head">Select</h4>
<h4 id="summary-head">Summary</h4>
</div>
```

**Code snippet 2**

```
<div class="col9 single-product" id="wide-left">
    <div class="product-name hidden-lg">
        <h2><span>Reebok Ventilator x Mita</span> <em class="stockcode"><span>M48281</span></em></h2>
    </div>
  <!-- end of .product-name -->
  <div class="row unexpanded" id="product-info">
      <div class="col4 product-pic-width">
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: @TRGWII SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: When are you running your code?  After the page has loaded?  In the `<head>` section?

Comment: Are you sure your string is properly escaped? `innerHTML = "<div class="col9">"` won't work, because the " symbol will end the string in the middle of the divs class, use strings like this: `innerHTML = "<div class=\"col9\">"`

Comment: Where is the JavaScript that you've tried? Others have referenced it, so I imagine it was present at some point, could you possibly add it back to the question (or tell me where it is, if I'm somehow missing it)?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to illustrate the basics for modifying HTML using the snippet tool here:

```js
var snip1 = document.getElementById("snip1"),
  snip2 = document.getElementById("snip2");

setTimeout(function() {
  snip1.innerHTML = snip2.innerHTML;
}, 1000); // This code copies the HTML from within snip2 to snip1.

setTimeout(function() {
  snip2.innerHTML = "";
}, 2000); // This code clears snip2.

setTimeout(function() {
  snip1.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.color = "blue";
}, 3000); // This code changes the CSS for <span> within snip1.

setTimeout(function() {
  snip2.textContent = snip1.innerHTML
}, 4000); // This code copies the HTML from snip1 as text into snip2.
```

```html
<div>
  Here is some <span id="snip1"></span> content!
</div>
<div>
  Here is some <span id="snip2"><span style="color:red">more</span></span>content!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the elements **after** the document object model ("DOM") has loaded, otherwise you will encounter errors.

```
document.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('wide-left').innerHTML = '<p>This is some HTML</p>';
}
```